# How can I get swftools installed?

Tags: 11.10, package-management

When I run `sudo apt-get install swftools` I am told E: Unable to locate package swftools. How can I get swftools installed?

Comment: what version of ubuntu?

Comment: @fossfreedom Sorry, I took that out of the title, but didn't add it to the tags. Adding now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a download page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/swftools/0.9.0-0ubuntu1) for the 32-bit version. The link is on the right under "Downloadable Files".

Just download the .deb file and double click it to open it and install it with Software Center.

You might also be interested in the two libraries at the bottom of [this page.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swftools/0.9.0-0ubuntu2)

Comment: thats the wrong version :S

Comment: @brunopereira81 It's the latest version they have a build for [on their site.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swftools) I downloaded it on 11.10 and it installed fine. If you want to download the latest source [form here](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/swftools/oneiric) you could probably compile it yourself.

Comment: okis, thought could be any problems with it for the lack of updates or something.

Answer (score 1):

Download last version from here - [SWFTOOLS Download](http://www.swftools.org/download.html)

Now [Installing a package from source](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aOneiric#Installing_a_package_from_source)

Or [Create a .deb package from source files](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aOneiric#Create_a_.deb_package_from_source_files)