# Installing swftools in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation, apt

I downloaded the deb, following the answer in this question:

[How can I get swftools installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72953/how-can-i-get-swftools-installed)

When I run:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/27270379/swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --install swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 swftools:i386 : Depends: libgif4:i386 (>= 4.1.6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: gsfonts:i386 but it is not installable
```

I tried calling `sudo apt-get -f install` which removed the manually installed package, and then installed libgif4 and gsfonts using apt-get, however libgif4 seems to be the wrong version (I'm thinking 4.1.9 as it's the latest), and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to install version 4.1.6. And as far as I can tell gsfonts is installed, I'm not sure why I'm getting that error message.

What should I do? I need to batch convert 92 animated gif images to web-optimised swf, and I was planning on doing this using gif2swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing from this PPA:

ppa:guilhem-fr/swftools

and report back of any dependence issues.

Comment: That's amazing. How did you find that PPA? It appears to have installed without any issues. I installed `swftools`. I can run pdf2swf, however cannot run gif2swf. It simply states that the command does not exist. Any ideas? I'm running `find` on the system now.

Comment: @abkai: did you get anywhere with your problem? I've encountered exactly the same difficulty